# Zend Framework 2 mysql view

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db

I've scoured the site and other places and haven't found a complete solution. I'm a newbie to ZF2 and have worked through the album example and set-up Table Gateways etc, but now I need to be able to query a mysql view and return those results to my function.

I have no idea what i should be calling in my class or what I should be modifying in order to achieve it.

I was hoping a few of my beginners books would show it but I can't easily find it. Could I hook into some of my Zf1 code?

Any comments or helpful weblinks would be gratefully received as i know I need to devote more time to learning these basics fully.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Service config and factories

- http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable
- http://www.maltblue.com/tutorial/zend-framework-2-servicemanager

### View Helper

- http://zf2dev.com/2013/03/19/how-to-write-custom-view-helper-in-zend-framework-2/

Comment: Cheers Remi, that's helped me :)